# In ansible playbook for role, just call specific task file, other than main.yml

Tags: ansible

I have simple role to install Weblogic server; And now I want to add a deinstall.yml task file.

At the moment I created a new simple playbook, and want to execute the file tasks/deinstall.yml with it.
How can I accomplish that please? My latest approach was with tags... is this a possible way? When I tested it, the main.yml was executed, the blocks and tasks there are without tags.

```
- hosts: alf_sandbox
  roles:
  - role: Weblogic
    vars:
      domain: TODO
    tags: deinstall
```

part of role directory

```
├── tasks
│   ├── deinstall.yml
│   ├── main.yml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example of tags doesn't filter but adds the tag deinstall to each task in the role. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tags.html#adding-tags-to-roles

You can use  tags by including deinstall from main.yml and setting the never tag:

```
 - include_tasks: deinstall
   tags: [ never, deinstall ]
```

Then ask Ansible to only run tasks tagged with deinstall  `ansible-playbook ./weblogic.yml --tags deinstall`

Another option is include_role using the tasks_from option:

```
   tasks:
   - name: Run tasks/deinstall.yml from Weblogic
      ansible.builtin.include_role:
        name: Weblogic
        tasks_from: deinstall
```

But often an uninstall can just be a seperate playbook. This keeps your role clean and often there is very little overlap between install/configure and uninstall tasks.